# How to print Google Test output to a text file?

Tags: c++, c, bash, cmake, googletest

I have gtest up and running using code as shown below. I would like to print the test output to a text file as opposed to displaying it in the console. Is there a way of doing this?

I run the tests using `cmake` from the console: `cmake CMakeLists.txt && make && ./runTests` .

```
#include "cw-test.c"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(InputValidationTest, ValidateEntryLine)
{
    ...
}

...

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Comment: Would this work for you: `cmake CMakeLists.txt && make && ./runTests &> test_output.txt` (see [this](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/FAQ#The_Google_Test_output_is_buried_in_a_whole_bunch_of_log_message))?

Comment: @crayzeewulf Yes! Perfect thanks. Put it in an answer and get some points. Will that work for any program or is it gtest related?

Comment: RobotEyes, done. Also, that type of [redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) will work for any command you run in a shell.

Comment: bash & cmake independent: [gtest_output option](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#generating-an-xml-report).
Windows, VS: the options `--gtest_output=xml` and `--gtest_output=xml:./` work with the result in the current folder (the one of the solution, I think).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect the output of your `runTests` command to a file:

```
cmake CMakeLists.txt && make && ./runTests > test_output.txt
```

Also, see [this](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/FAQ#The_Google_Test_output_is_buried_in_a_whole_bunch_of_log_message) which explains why you do not need the `&` I had used in my comment. As Awaken's answer says, the `&` redirects both the `stdout` and `stderr` to the same file. But since `googletest` output always goes to `stdout` you may leave out the `&`.

Comment: But the code under test itself may be logging to stderr. Those printouts will not be in the output file if you use only >.

Answer (score 2):

crayzeewulf's comment will work for any Unix program. What "&>" means is to redirect output in "stdout" and "stderr" to some other location you specify.

More information can be found here.
http://www.mathinfo.u-picardie.fr/asch/f/MeCS/courseware/users/help/general/unix/redirection.html